# Infinite Scroll back position Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, infinite-scroll

I use Infinite Scroll with Lazysizes to list my products in WooCommerce.
When I click on a product link and want to get back, I end up at the top again.
So I tried this so I can get back to where I left off:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { jQuery(window).off('popstate.nmshop'); }, 150);
});
```

This works fine but only in Safari, how can I get it to work in Chrome?